# Trim column names of a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

How can i trim column-names of a `DataTable`?

Suppose the column-name in the `DataTable` is `"Name "`, I want it to be changed to `"Name"`.
Everything else like data should not change. How to do that?

Comment: `"Name ".Trim() = "Name";`

Comment: I want to do this for all columns. Like dataBle.Columns....something like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the [`ColumnName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnname(v=vs.90).aspx).

```
foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Trim();
```

Comment: Still surprised at the downvote

Comment: @Habib Same here. +1 from me.

Comment: I +1 but I hate giving into people like the OP it doesn't seem like he tried anything and was not interested in learning just in getting the code from someone... Not talking about you @Tim Schmelter

Comment: Hello, I was actually looking for a Lamda Expression instead of a simple for each loop

Comment: @user3787610: why a  lambda expression? You cannot solve everything with  lambdas. Linq is not appropriate if you want to modify something.